# Where are the postgres logs?

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I'm using DBeaver to connect the postgres db and want to access the logs via DBeaver.

I run the command below to find log destination and got stderr as the location.

```
show log_destination ;
```

How can I reach that file on DB app? FYI, I want all logs, not the logs that are from DBeaver.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On recent PostgreSQL versions, that is simple:

```
SELECT  pg_current_logfile();
```

For old versions, proceed as follows:

- Verify that the logging collector is started:

  ```
  SHOW logging_collector;
  ```

  - If not, the location of the log depends on how PostgreSQL was started.
  - If yes, the log will be in `log_directory`:

    ```
    SHOW log_directory;
    ```

    If that is a relative path, it is relative to the PostgreSQL data directory.

Since the log file is on the database server, you probably won't be able to access it with a client tool.

Comment: how do I read this log?

Comment: @Telion You need shell access to the database server machine. On hosted databases, there may be other facilities.

Comment: the function `pg_current_logfile()` gave me the name of the file and then I was able to find it with `find / -type f -name "postgresql-Tue.log"` here `/var/lib/pgsql/14/data/log/postgresql-Tue.log` in a CentOS 7 server

Answer (score 12):

[https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/10/how-to-show-queries-log-in-postgresql.html#:~:text=The%20location%20of%20the%20log,pgsql%2Fdata%2Fpg_log%2F%20](https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/10/how-to-show-queries-log-in-postgresql.html#:%7E:text=The%20location%20of%20the%20log,pgsql%2Fdata%2Fpg_log%2F%20).

In Ubuntu is under  `/var/log/postgresql`

Answer (score 11):

You can run `pg_lsclusters`.

```
> pg_lsclusters                                                                                                          
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
11  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/11/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log
```

Comment: This worked for me when `SELECT  pg_current_logfile();` returned an empty value.

Comment: This is a Debian-specific thing.

Answer (score 2):

To find the correct postgres log, even if it is not running as a service (If you have admin root privilage at most.):

```
sudo lsof | grep postgres | grep '2w'
```

or

```
 lsof | grep postgres | grep '1w'
```

Where 1w and 2w mean for the File Descriptors (FD) of stdout and stderr respectively. Thees FD are opened in writing only mode (w) to proper log file. It is true fol all postgres processes.

[image]

or from psql:

```
postgres@postgres=# \! sudo lsof | grep postgres | grep 1w
```

[image]

Comment: use `lsof -n`  to avoid making DNS  lookups. (you get faster results)

Answer (score 0):

In Mac when installing Postgres with `brew` you can find it here:
`/opt/homebrew/var/log/postgres.log`